# node.js express variable undefined?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do this line

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate...)

And the router is in my directory's router folder. I've exported it as a module and am using it in my app.js file.

In app.js I have my requires in this order:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var User = require('./models/models.js')
```

So shouldn't the routes be able to access passport?

This is my routes/index

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var errors = req.flash('error');
})
module.exports = router;
```

This is the beginning of my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var User = require('./models/models.js');
var PassportLocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
```

Comment: Post the code that you used to export the module.

Comment: Have you tried `require("./config/passport")(passport);` ?

Comment: Added code in, haven't required config as I don't have such a folder

Comment: Didn't realize you had to require (passport) in the module, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to re-include passport as a variable inside the module.

Answer (score 0):

Add `var passport = require('passport');` at the top of your `routes/index.js` file.

**Or**, wrap your router in a `module.exports = function(passport) {};` and pass `passport` into the `routes` requirement in `app.js`.

Like this: `var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);`